# Using updated dotenv value

Tags: python

How do I get the updated value of .env after applying set_key?
Not sure if I'm misunderstanding something, but shouldn't os.getenv() return the new value after I've changed it?

.env

```
TEST="123"
```

main.py

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, set_key
import os

load_dotenv()
print(os.getenv("TEST"))
set_key(".env", "TEST", "456")
print(os.getenv("TEST"))
```

output

```
123
123
```

Looking back into .env, I do see that the value has been updated to "456". How do i get the second output to reflect the change?

Comment: Call `load_dotenv()` again maybe?

Comment: Nope doesn't work. @rperroen answer did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
os.environ["TEST"] = "456"
```

instead if you want to change the current environment variable.

```
set_key(".env", "TEST", "456")
```

will update the value in the .env file, so the new value will be accessible the next time the file is read or `load_dotenv()` is called

Comment: I see, thanks. So if I want to both change the environment variable and set it, I would have to call both?

Comment: If you want to update/generate a config file for example. If you simply want to update the environment variable, you should use `os.environ` instead

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1: use dotenv to load all env variables and os module to set and get env variables.

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv(".env")
print(os.getenv("TEST"))
os.environ["TEST"] = "456"
print(os.getenv("TEST"))
```

Approach 2: Use dotenv to load, set and get env variables.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, set_key, get_key

load_dotenv(".env")
print(get_key(".env", "TEST"))
set_key(".env", "TEST", "456")
print(get_key(".env", "TEST"))
```